# Units of a quantum electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, units, second-quantization

The recalling $\mathbf p \rightarrow \mathbf p -q\mathbf A$, the vector potential has units $$ \langle \mathbf{A} \rangle \leftrightarrow\Big[\frac{\text{momentum} }{\text{charge} }\Big]$$
If we take the commutation relations to be
$$ \big[ a(\mathbf p,\, \alpha),\,a^\dagger(\mathbf p',\, \alpha') \big] = \delta_{\alpha\alpha'} \delta(\mathbf p'-\mathbf p )$$
The right hand side has units of $\frac{1}{\mathrm{momentum}^3}$, so $a$ and $a^\dagger$ would have units of $\frac{1}{\mathrm{momentum}^{3/2}}$
.If we write the quantized $\mathbf A$ field as
$$\mathbf{A} = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}\Big(e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}/\hbar}\mathbf {a}^{-} (\mathbf{p})+e^{-i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x}/\hbar}\mathbf {a} ^{+}(\mathbf{p}) \Big)  $$ 
and $\big(\mathbf{a}^-(\mathbf p)\big)^i = \sum_\alpha \big(\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{ \mathbf{p}\alpha}\big)^i a(\mathbf p,\, \alpha) $, and polarization vector $\boldsymbol \epsilon$ being unitless by convention. 
This appears to leave $\mathbf{A}$ with units of $\mathrm{momentum}^{3/2}\mathrm{time}^{1/2} $. However it should have units of $\frac{\text{momentum} }{\text{charge}}$. How can the quantized $\mathbf A$ field be written to have the correct units in the SI system?

Comment: Why are you assigning units to the delta function?

Comment: The dirac delta integrates to 1 by definition. So it must have the appropriate units of $(\frac{1}{\text{units of argument}})^{\mathrm{dimension}} $.

Comment: There's a bunch of $\hbar$ and $c$ missing in your formulas. Restore them and units will agree. Also, in the $\hbar = c = 1$ system momentum is inverse time and charge is dimensionless, so units also agree in your formulas.

Comment: Would you elaborate,  Solenodon Paradoxus? I had already tried inserting $\hbar$, $c$, and $\epsilon_0$ in various ways but I could not get the units to agree. Also, what do you mean by "system momentum is inverse time" ?

Comment: You still have a couple of them missing. E.g. I see no $c$ in your formulas whatsoever, which couldn't be right since electrodynamics is a relativistic theory. I leave it up to you to figure out where it belongs. I meant that if you set $\hbar = c = 1$ (which is called the natural units in QFT) effectively erasing them and making your formulas correct — then you only have a single dimensionful unit left (energy = momentum = inverse length = inverse time). In which case time to the power of $1/2$ cancels in your formula. Also in this system charge is dimensionless. Thus the dimensions agree.